# Multiple conditional fields in a VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to adjust these two statements into one since the outcome of both is to either display the 'Age' field or not?

```
<apex:outputField value="{!con.Age__c}" rendered="{!NOT(con.Do_Not_Show_Birthdate__c) && (con.Deceased__c == 'Yes')}"/>
            
<apex:outputField value="{!con.Age__c}" rendered="{!con.Do_Not_Show_Birthdate__c && bViewBirthdate && (con.Deceased__c == 'Yes')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the OR (`||`) operator here:

```
(NOT(con.Do_Not_Show_Birthdate__c) || bViewBirthdate) && (con.Deceased__c == 'Yes')
```

This says "If Do Not Show Birthday is not checked OR bViewBirthDate is true, AND Deceased__c equals Yes, then render this field."

Comment: Thanks isn't, {!con.Do_Not_Show_Birthdate__c && bViewBirthdate && (con.Deceased__c == 'Yes')} saying if do not show birthdate is checked and bViewBirthdate is true and deceased  = yes then display field? But the first line is a bit different, it's saying if do not show birthdate is not checked and deceased = yes then show field? So there is that slight difference in the do not show birthdate entries

Comment: @gh0st If you write a truth table, you'll see that my optimized version and the original are actually the same. It just takes some reasoning through it to verify that it is indeed correct.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. I've been testing it out. However after seeing the results, the field does not appear if the either of the arguments are not met and therefore the layout of the VisualForce page changes in ways I do not want. Is there a way to render the field as we discussed earlier but if neither arguments are met then display a blank field? Thanks.

Comment: @gh0st You can use an apex:pageBlockSectionItem with no content to act as a placeholder. The render condition can be the exact opposite by using another NOT: `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!NOT((NOT(con.Do_Not_Show_Birthdate__c) || bViewBirthdate) && (con.Deceased__c == 'Yes'))}" />`

Comment: Thanks. Would something like this work, I know it's for picklists, but could it be modified for my situation? 

rendered="{!IF(Object.picklistfieldapiname1 ='picklist value 1' || lead.Buyer_Type__c ='picklist value 2' ,true,false)}

Where the false value could be a blank space or nbsp?

Comment: @gh0st Yes, it can. By the way, Boolean operators are already Boolean values, no need for the if part: `rendered="{!Object.picklistfieldapiname1 ='picklist value 1' || lead.Buyer_Type__c ='picklist value 2'}"`